# getting index value of field that in the array in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

i getting view code output as different button with respect to sitename like this pune on button and blore button ;
if i click on pune button i want pass the sitename as pune to query : @getval= P7accessinfo.where("sitename= 'pune'")
how to get the coresponding sitename when click on button plg help me sir

```
uuid  | sitename |    ipaddr      | descri   | username |  pswd  
 1234 | blore    | 1              | qwe      | ii       | 323232
 123  | us       | 1              | assd     | 123456   |  898
 12   | blore    |www             | a        | asa      |  34


         <div class=form-actions>
               <% @sitename.each do | rec | %>
                  <a id="<%=rec.site%>" onclick= "getTaskId()" data-rel="tooltip" title="Total access in bangalore." 
                    class="well span2 top-block" href="/p7_addcontroller">
                        <span class="icon32 icon-green icon-Users"></span>
                          <div><%=rec.site%></div>
                            <div id="loading-indicator" style="display: none;">
                              <%= image_tag("peregrine-loader.gif") %>
                        </div>
                       <div class="counter"><%=rec.cnt%></div>
                            <span class="notification">today</span>
                </a>
             <% end%>
             <!-- Summary counters - END -->
        </div>
```

This view will create different button according sitename of database.
   if i click on each(ex:sitename=pune) button show only the pune related database
 and if i click on sitename=blore button show only blore related database

I want the code how to get the index value of buttons then i will pass that to query and display that corresponding sitename database

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you might need to use each_with_index instead of each

```
<% @sitename.each_with_index do | rec, i | %>
```

where i is the index variable.

Comment: tnank u sir ,i need one more help get the value of array each time into varible i try this but not working var v=document.getElement byId(<%rec.site%>);

Comment: I'm still unclear what you are trying to do Can you give me a full description of the scenario or post your full code?